# Compound word search engine design

Tags: sql-server, search, full-text-search, search-engine

We have a search function using SQL Server's Full-Text Search. It is an any word search and works very well.

However, quotation marks around compound terms don't work with Full-Text Search.

So, currently a search for "peanut butter" returns peanut butter first, then peanuts and butter, etc.

We want the system to recognize certain compound terms and exclude all else.

So a search for: coffee ethiopian ground - would still perform an any word search.

However, a search for: ground coffee - would recognize the compound term and return only exact matches for "ground coffee".

Is the only way to do this to build your own dictionary of compound terms? Are there any other options?

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx), SQL Server should honor your double quotes and match only compound word matches.

I suspect you are using FREETEXT or FREETEXTTABLE which performs more of a natural-language search and ignores double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I know about CONTAINSTABLE etc. - I prefer FREETEXTTABLE for an any words search. I'm more interested in how to switch between the 2 by recognizing compound search terms as related and putting virtual quotation marks around them. Is the only way to do this by building up a dictionary of such terms?